# Does C sign extend or zero extend constants?

Tags: c

Does C sign extend constants or zero extend them?
For example:

```
int a = 123 & 0x3
```

is the 0x3 zero extend or sign extended?
Also in general, what things are zero extended in C and what are sign extended?

Thanks!

Comment: sign or unsigned, shouldn't they evaluate to same as its a positive integer?

Comment: You should generally only use the '&'-operator on unsigned expressions. Then the behaviour is predictable. Try unsigned int a = 123U & 0x3U

Comment: @iolo: The behaviour of the OP's code snippet is also predictable.

Comment: @Oli: really? Even if c doesn't specify how a signed integer is mapped into memory? That sounds weird... (Maybe I'm overlooking something :D)

Comment: @iolo: I'm not sure why the mapping to storage bits would affect this.

Comment: @Oli: As far as my understanding goes '&' was supposed to be a bitwise operator which would then operate on the mapped bits to produce a result. So it should be dependent on how the integer is mapped to bits.

Comment: @iolo: But whatever the mapping is, it is consistent.  So whether it's lsb-first, msb-first, or something else, the result will always be the same, as neither of these values exceeds the range of an `int`.

Comment: Positive signed values have representation identical to the same value in the corresponding unsigned type (assuming it fits). And the representation of positive values is always required to be pure binary anyway (since only 3 representations of signed values are allowed and they all represent positive values the same way).

Comment: @R: I didn't mean endianness issues. But C does not specify how the sign of the integer will be encoded together with the value bits. This should effectively eliminate any portability of bitwise operations on signed integers, shouldn't it?

Comment: @iolo: See section 6.2.6.2 of the (C99) standard.  The representation of the value bits for positive values is mandated to the be the same as for the corresponding unsigned type.  So if we're talking about in-range positive values (which we are), then the result will be the same as for `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C standard does not mandate whether the implementation uses 2's complement, 1's complement, or something else.  So the representation of negative values is not mandated either.

However, in your particular case, `0x3` is a positive value, so sign-extension and zero-extension are the same thing!

Comment: Perhaps what would be more interesting to OP is that **all integer literals** in C have non-negative value, even something like `0xffffffff`.

Comment: what about something like int a = 0xf? will a be -1? or 15?

Comment: @Andrew: As @R. says, integer literals will always be interpreted as positive (or zero) values.

Answer (score 0):

As far as sign-extending, it depends if the values are signed or unsigned.

However, in your example, the high bit will not be set so it doesn't matter. The result would be zero extended.